# UITableView didEndDisplaying not called when video is playing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, video, webview

I already tried to find here a similar question without success.

I have a *UITableView* with various kinds of contents and cells. In particular, it can show a custom *UITableViewCell* with a *WKWebView*.
Sometimes this web view has an autoplay video that starts when I configure the cell on **willDisplayCell**.
Because of this autoplay feature, when I scroll up/down, the cell does not call the delegate method **didEndDisplayingCell** and the video stays active in the background. The user needs to close the viewController or the whole App.

---

I tried to save on a list all the dequeued cells with web view and on **scrollViewDidEndDecelerating** manually set the content of the saved cell's web view to HTML "" using:

```
cell.webView?.loadHTMLString("", baseURL: nil)
```

In this way, the web view properly stops playing the video in the background but the problem is that even using this approach the cell is not enqueued and the **didEndDisplayingCell:** is not called, so when I scroll to that cell again, I can't redo correct configuration to reload the web view.

Do you have some tips or tricks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved with a workaround. Basically the cell isn't recycled for some strange reason, regarding how the webView handles video in that case.
So I save all those cells as instance property in a `Set` and in `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` I check if the cell is still visible. If it's not visible, I manually remove the webView from its superview.

```
var advTableViewCells = Set<AdvertisingTableViewCell>() // here I save the cell retrieved in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` 

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {  
    var cellsToRemove = Set<AdvertisingTableViewCell>() // save the cell to remove in a temporary set, to avoid removing element in a forEach
    advTableViewCells.forEach { cell in
        if !tableView.visibleCells.contains(cell) {
            cell.webView?.stopLoading()
            cell.webView?.removeFromSuperview()
            cell.webView = nil
            cellsToRemove.insert(cell)
        }
    }
    cellsToRemove.forEach { cell in
        self.advTableViewCells.remove(cell)
    }
}
```

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio With that, does the cell get reused, `prepareForReuse()` is called, as well as `didEndDisplay...` (in its web-less state only, of course)??

Comment: @AmitaiB as far as I remember yes, those methods are called